# PHP if/else not working as intended

Tags: php, mysql, select, if-statement

Below is some code I am using to check if a field says "CIT" to display that as the selected item in the html select box.  Elseif the field says "CSE", display "CSE" as selected and CIT/CSE in the drop downs respectively if one or the other is selected in the database.  No matter what is in the database field the code always seems to use the first if statement.  So courses with "CSE" as course_major are showing "CIT" as the first option in the drop down, however it shouldn't be this way.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$bg = ($bg=='#B39C56' ? '#000000' : '#0A0A0A');
    echo '<tr>
    <form action="edit_course.php" method="post">
    <!--Next Course
First Line of Table
--><td>Major:</td>

<td style="text-align:left">';
if ($row['course_major'] = "CIT") {
echo'   <select name="course_major" class="rounded">
    <option value="'.$row['course_major'].'">'.$row['course_major'].'</option>
    <option value="CSE">CSE</option>
    </select>';

}  elseif ($row['course_major'] = "CSE")  {
echo'   <select name="course_major" class="rounded">
    <option value="'.$row['course_major'].'">'.$row['course_major'].'</option>
    <option value="CIT">CIT</option>
    </select>';
};

echo'</td>
........................
```

Answer (score 2):

Usual mistake; you have an assignment rather than an equality test in your if and elseif clauses. Change both = -s to ==.

Comment: Gah, that was so simple.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning rather than comparing.

```
if ( $x = 3 ) ...
```

assigns the value of 3 to $x, and then tests the result of that expression, 3, to see if the value is true.  It is the same as saying

```
$x = 3;
if ( $x ) ...
```

You mean to use the equality test:

```
if ( $x == 3 ) ...
```